# How to modify the 1st element of a collection in a slightly different way than other in Elixir using Enum.map?

Tags: elixir

I have a list of "struct". I'm using `Enum.map(...)` to modify them. What I want is to modify the 1st element **only** in a slightly different way and the rest should be modified **in a standard way.** What's the best way to do so?

I've tried zipping my list of structs with a range of numbers and it looked unusually complex for such a simple task.

Comment: Apply Enum.with_index(...) over the list and after apply Enum.map(...) to modify them ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a `list` and two functions `modify1` and `modify2` respectively, you might split the list into `head` and `tail`, apply your transformations and glue the list back:

```rb
with [h | t] <- list,
     h <- modify1.(h),
     t <- Enum.map(& modify2/1),
 do: [h | t]
```

Another option would be to intersperse call to map with call to `Enum.with_index/1`:

```rb
list
|> Enum.with_index()
|> Enum.map(fn
     {h, 0} -> modify1.(h)
     {t, _} -> modify2.(t)
   end)
```

Comment: using `with` for this is elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enum.with_index`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#with_index/2) then call `Enum.map` matching on the `index` to do the necessary modification. Like

```
struct_list
|> Enum.with_index()
|> Enum.map(fn 
    {data, 0} ->
       # first struct modification code here
       modify_first(data)
    {data, _index} ->
       # standard modification
       modify(data)
end)
```

Comment: exactly what I said above

Answer (score 1):

Apply `Enum.with_index(...)` over the list and after apply `Enum.map(...)` to modify them.